# Kivy malfunction on raspberry pi touch LCD

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, lcd

So i am having a strange issue with my kivy app on my raspberry pi touch LCD. I made my app with a clear background so i am able to see the raspbian UI, the problem is when i touch the screen the cursor is working for both the kivy app and the raspbian UI at the same time. This is an issue because i keep closing the app by closing the LX terminal. Also, the touch input gets inverted when i am on the kivy app. So i keep clicking on the opposite direction. I have already tried to look through the config.ini file but can't seem to find anything that helps. 
This is the source code for the .ini file:
https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/config.html
Maybe some one can understand this better than i can.

By the way, i am using a raspberry pi B+ with raspbian jessie.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am having same issue and can't find solution that works for touch and mouse.

Comment: Same issue here on Raspberry Pi OS buster with kivy-1.11.1.